# What feature or ability lets a paladin share Smite Evil with her party?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, paladin, content-identification

What is the feat/trait/spell that allows a Paladin to share her smite evil with her party? I cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 12):

### Aura of Justice

You must be thinking of the [aura of justice](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin/#TOC-Aura-of-Justice-Su-) which allows a paladin to grant allies the ability to smite evil:

> At 11th level, a paladin can expend two uses of her smite evil ability to grant the ability to smite evil to all allies within 10 feet, using her bonuses